# Image of a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ under the reciprocal map

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Given $K = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |z-3i| = 2\}$, what is the image of $K$ under the function $f$ defined by $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$?

By using the fact that the reciprocal map of a circle not passing through zero is another circle not passing through zero, I could immediately deduce that the result is a circle, with closest point to the origin being $\frac{1}{i} = -i$ and furthest point from origin being $\frac{1}{5i} = -5i$, with centre in the midpoint of these two.

However, I seem to not have gotten it algebraically, and am unsure which method is incorrect.

My attempt:
Let $w \in f(K)$. Then for $w = \frac{1}{z}$ and $z \in K$,
$$|\frac{1}{w} - 3i| = 2 \\ |1 - 3i w| = 2|w| \\ (1-3iw)\overline{(1-3iw)}= 2w\overline{w}\\ 1 + 3i\overline{w} - 3iw +9w\overline{w} = 2w\overline{w}\\7w\overline{w} + 3i\overline{w} - 3iw = -1 \\ |w\overline{w} + \frac{3i}{7}| = -\frac{1}{7} +\frac{9}{49} = \frac{2}{49} $$
which is a circle with radius $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{7}$ with centre at $\frac{-3i}{7}$ which doesn't seem to be consistent with my first answer.

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt2}{49}$?

Comment: Sorry, was a typo $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{7}$, but still seems to be inconsistent with the first answer

Comment: You basic idea isn't bad but $\frac1{5i}=-\frac{1}5i\neq -5i$

Comment: I see, I also spotted the mistake that gets rid of my inconsistent answer. I tried doing it a few times and didn't get it out weirdly... thanks!

Comment: Squaring both sides, RHD must be $4|w|^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$3|i/3+w|=2|w|$

This mean $w$ is appolonius' circle of which $\frac{-i}3*\frac35$, $\frac{-i}{3}*3$ are edges of its diameter.